# Separate sequelize models in separate folders and join all together

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a complicated task to do. I need to separate my sequelize models in separate folders inside the models folder, just like this structure:

```
├── node_modules
├── src
|    └── models
|        ├──settings
|        |  ├── user.js
|        |  └── location.js
|        ├──stock
|        |  ├── stock.js
|        |  └── products.js
|        └── index.js
```

Today, I have all models in models root folder, together with index.js, in a way that I can call every model from controllers as

```
const { users, stock } = require("../../models")
```

The code inside index.js is like this:

```
"use strict"

const fs = require("fs")
const path = require("path")
const Sequelize = require("sequelize")
const basename = path.basename(__filename)
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development"
const envConfigs = require("../config/config")
const config = envConfigs[env]
const db = {}

let sequelize
if (config.url) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.url, config)
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.database,
    config.username,
    config.password,
    config
  )
}

fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter((file) => {
    return (
      file.indexOf(".") !== 0 && file !== basename && file.slice(-3) === ".js"
    )
  })
  .forEach((file) => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(
      sequelize,
      Sequelize.DataTypes
    )
    db[model.name] = model
  })

Object.keys(db).forEach((modelName) => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db)
  }
})

db.sequelize = sequelize

module.exports = db
```

This was automaticly created using sequelize-cli.

I think that I need some search inside index.js and concatenate folders and files into Model variable inside index.js, in such a way that I can use the models like "model.settings.user" to do associations or calling the objects in controllers.

Comment: I read this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32546148/break-sequelize-models-in-separate-folders
but i can't get working for my project (and that's maybe because the sequelize version changes)

Comment: What error did you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I was able to get the index.js working properly! This is the code for anyone that need it (having this code in the index.js, it will search in all folders and put all models name files into const "model"

```
"use strict"

const fs = require("fs")
const path = require("path")
const Sequelize = require("sequelize")
const basename = path.basename(__filename)
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development"
const envConfigs = require("../config/config")
const config = envConfigs[env]
const db = {}

let sequelize
if (config.url) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.url, config)
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.database,
    config.username,
    config.password,
    config
  )
}

const files = []
const sortDir = (maniDir) => {
  const folders = []
  const CheckFile = (filePath) => fs.statSync(filePath).isFile()
  const sortPath = (dir) => {
    fs.readdirSync(dir)
      .filter((file) => file.indexOf(".") !== 0 && file !== "index.js")
      .forEach((res) => {
        const filePath = path.join(dir, res)
        if (CheckFile(filePath)) {
          files.push(filePath)
        } else {
          folders.push(filePath)
        }
      })
  }
  folders.push(maniDir)
  let i = 0
  do {
    sortPath(folders[i])
    i += 1
  } while (i < folders.length)
}
sortDir(__dirname)

files.forEach((file) => {
  const model = require(file)(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes)
  db[model.name] = model
})

Object.keys(db).forEach((modelName) => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db)
  }
})

db.sequelize = sequelize

module.exports = db
```